# Upload photo on Ionic 3

Tags: html, css, angular, firebase, ionic3

I am uploading photo using native html file input, which work fine on iOS but when I try this in android the it doesn't do anything.

My `html`

```
<input id="photo-input" type="file" name="file" (change)="onChange($event)" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg">
```

My `ts` file.

```
onChange(event) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort this out by writing this, which I was able load images from the gallery.

```
<input id="photo-input" type="file" name="file" (change)="onChange($event)" accept="image/*">
```

Answer (score 0):

To upload/download files using an Ionic app, use the File transfer plugin from Ionic Native.

[File Transfer Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/)

Comment: I don't want to use cordova for this just native html.

Comment: This is not possible with Ionic. Another workaround would be to send the image using FormData. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData